# How to add calculated/formula fields into Doctrine Entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to use the equivalent of Hibernate's `@Formula` annotations in Doctrine entities.

My issue is concerning a `datetime` field that I would like to render in a certain format (RFC2822) so that I can use it easily in Datatables javascript.

I would like to avoid using the `render` features from Datatables.
I would like to use this entity as usual from the `QueryBuilder`.
I have already tried to implement the `JsonSerializable` class in my entity, which is quite working well, but the ManyToOne underlying associations are not json_encoded properly.

Here is a sample of my entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User{

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $startDate;

//Getters & setters...
}
```

I use it like this in my UserRepository :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('l, u')
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->join('u.location', 'l')
    ->where('u.userId=1');
$data['json']=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Using `getArrayResult()` does not change my concern.

I would like to create a new method (or maybe a private static field) like `getStartDateRFC()` in my entity:

```
public function getStartDateRFC(){
    return $this->startDate->format(DateTime::RFC2822);
}
```

Would it be possible without having to use the heavy [Custom Mapping Types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html#custom-mapping-types) from Doctrine?

Comment: Which Serializer are you currently using? Symfony Serializer Component (which Normalizer?) or JMS Serializer?

Comment: @LBA I am using the standard one from PHP. `class User implements JsonSerializable`. The `json_encode` function triggers the the `jsonSerialize()` method of my entity, but it's a pity that you have to reparse every property/method by yourself and that underlying collections are not serialized.

Comment: then use a different Normalizer like Object or GetSet which allows you to add your calculated attributes etc.

Comment: Well, I'm not under symfony but with codeigniter. I will take a look if it's possible to use these libraries. Thank you.

Comment: @LBA : Wouldn't it be a good option to create a custom DQL function to convert my date as defined here? [link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

Comment: Just for the feedback, another way to do is to use a PostLoad method as described here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478536/virtual-generated-columns-in-doctrine